# How can I create an event in google calendar and not have it on trash?

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, composer-php, google-calendar-api

How can I create an event in google calendar and not have it on trash?
I was researching on Google Calendar API ( https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert ) how to create an event on the calendar, the insert works fine, the API returns with status: 'confirmed'.
But in the calendar, the event does not appear.
I looked at Google Calendar API and there the status is "canceled", so my events appear on the trash.
I'm not sure of what is happening, someone knows how to create an event on google calendar that does not goes to trash?

[image]

```php
<?php
class Calendar
{
    private $calendarId         = 'primary';
    private $service            = null;
    private $client             = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client([
            'scopes' => [
                Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR,
                Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY,
                Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS,
                Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS_READONLY,
            ]
        ]);
        $this->service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client->getClient());
    }

    public function eventAdd()
    {
        $email = 'seuemail@gmail.com';

        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
        $event->setSummary('Vamos ver agora ;)');
        $event->setStatus('confirmed');
        $start_datetime = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $start_datetime->setDateTime('2019-10-10T15:00:00.000-03:00');
        $start_datetime->setTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $event->setStart($start_datetime);
        $end_datetime = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $end_datetime->setDateTime('2019-10-10T20:00:00.000-03:00');
        $end_datetime->setTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $event->setEnd($end_datetime);
        $reminder = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminder();
        $reminder->setMethod('popup');
        $reminder->setMinutes(10);
        $reminders = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders();
        $reminders->setUseDefault(false);
        $reminders->setOverrides(array($reminder));
        $event->setReminders($reminders);

        $attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
        $attendee1->setEmail($email);
        $attendee1->setResponseStatus('accepted');
        $attendees = array($attendee1);
        $event->attendees = $attendees;
        $optParams = array('sendNotifications' => true, 'maxAttendees' => 1);
        $event = $this->service->events->insert($this->calendarId, $event, $optParams);

        var_dump($event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [an open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140819378) for this problem in Issue Tracker.

As a workaround, you can use your actual calendar ID instead of just 'primary'. This small change should solve your issue.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Here was the same thing sending the trash, and does not appear in the calendar grid so I need arrow only grid and not trash, as you said before "primary" and already made two types used "primary" and the other email @. .... iam.gserviceaccount.com and gave same thing. I'll keep seeing if I can figure something out